# How to fix mistakes of a JSON data which is in a txt file using any language?

Tags: json, parsing, twitter

I am getting tweet information from twitter API 1.1 in JSON format and i save them in a txt file. But some lines have mistakes. Here you can see ;

```html
{
"data":
[
   {
    "created_at": "Fri Jul 24 17:40:54 +0000 2015",
    "id": 624635378344030200,
    "id_str": "624635378344030208",
    "text": "#FollowFriday @ragalan1974 @DiazCueto @ecoinnovatic for being top",
    "source": "<a href="https://commun.it" rel="nofollow">Commun.it</a>",
    "truncated": false
    }
 ]
}
```

"source" object contains quotes. so I cant parse. I need to remove those quotes. It should be like ;

```html
"source": "<a href=https://commun.it rel=nofollow>Commun.it</a>",
```

I tried to replace these in Java (read from txt - replace and write to .txt) and it works but source may be different for each tweet (e.g Commun.it, twitter for Android , twitter for IOS , web Browser, mobil web browser or various applications.) So I can't control all of theese by hand. For sure there must be a solution for all to remove these quotes. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to escape string values.

Comment: @marekful how can i do it ? can you show me some examples pls ?

Comment: To start with, I doubt the JSON data comes from Twitter API in the form you posted. When there are quotes _inside a string value_, they should be single quotes or escapes doubles. `"source": "<a href='some'>thing</a>"` or `"source": "<a href=\"some\">thing</a>"`. The text is probably changed when you save it that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct it, the best solution is to do it through a program, and my advice is to use regexp, so you will be able to find and modify these exact pattern.

But you will not remove the quotes, you will juste escape them, like this:

```
 "source": "<a href=\"https://commun.it\" rel=\"nofollow\">Commun.it</a>",
```

Comment: could you show any example please (how to use it)? I am appreciated. That is the answer I was looking for. But unfortunately I dont know how to do..